# SQL data constraints doubts

Tags: mysql, sql, null, primary-key

In SQL, can you set a column that allows `null` values to be unique?

What happens if the table contains multiple rows with `null` value for that column?

What happens in case you specify a foreign key to that column in another table and a tuple in the referencing table contains a `null` value for the foreign key?

Comment: Why you do not try it?

Comment: @Jens You're helpful -_-....I am learning the basics still....I am clarifying my doubts....

Comment: You need to create a unique constraint... refer to this article
http://improvingsoftware.com/2010/03/26/creating-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-nulls-in-sql-server/
And add a where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many rows with `null` as you want in a column set with a Unique Index in mysql.    Check the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nullable` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `nullable` (`nullable`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INTO `test1` (`id`, `nullable`)
 VALUES
  (1, NULL),
(2, NULL),
(3, NULL);
```

You can add as many records as you want to this table with nulls in the nullable field.

I think I invented the name `nullable` :).